# Can anyone remember an online novel in which a nurse relives his teenage life again?

Tags: story-identification, novel

He was attending to a dying patient who granted his wish of reliving his life again and wakes up as a teen. The story is situated in Spokane.

Answer (score 8):

Strangely enough, even though this is a mind bogglingly obscure question, I'm pretty sure that the story you are looking for is *Doing It All Over* by Al Steiner. I particularly enjoyed the discussions in it about theories of the nature of time.

Comment: Fair warning for anyone doing a search on this, it is an adult story, and searching for the title will put several erotica sites up as suggested hits.